# How to close NavigationDrawer from a fragment?

Tags: android

I've got an Activity, where are two fragments inside (menu fragment) + content fragment.

Something like that:

http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/

But my menu (drawer) itself is a fragment too, where I replace the content fragment by clicking on the menu points (listview).

I want the Drawer is closing itself everything I click on menu element (listview element)

how can I do it inside the fragment?

thank u

Answer (score 0):

After You Commit Your Fragment Transition

```
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in your activity

```
public void closeDrawer()
{
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

and in your fragment use

```
((MyActivity)getActivity()).closeDrawer();
```

Comment: hmm i do not have any mDrawerList in my activity... what to do then?

Comment: replace mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList); to 
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(6027): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawers()' on a null object reference 

this error is commin, when I click on menu element

Comment: You must check that yout drawer_layout is not null. In the example you have posted the close line is the drawer.closeDrawer(navList); So change this line according to your implementation.